# PHP: Função como condição para um if

Tags: php, funções, if

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar uma função como condição para um `if`.

Exemplo:

```
function estaParaExpirar($data, $dias) {
    return(strtotime($data) < strtotime("+".$dias."days") );
}

if  estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10") {
    Echo "..."
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não só é possível, como é extremamente comum usar.

```
if (is_array($a)) {     // função que verifica se $a é uma array
                        // e retorna verdadeiro ou falso...

if (minha_funcao($a)) { // função criada pelo usuário e que também supõe-se
                        // que retorna verdadeiro ou falso...

if (estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10")) { // o seu exemplo, desde que também
                                       // retorne verdadeiro ou falso...
```

O **if** pode testar qualquer situação de comparação lógica, mesmo que um (ou todos) dos membros dessa comparação seja uma função.

Outro exemplo:

```
if (estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10") || estaParaExpirar($row[11], "20")) {
// verdadeiro se qualquer uma das duas situações resultar em verdadeiro...
```

Comment: No ultimo caso consigo colocar por exemplo:if (estaParaExpirar($row[10], "10")) ||(estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10")) {

Comment: @ChrisAdler, incluí outro exemplo na resposta.